# m to feet and inch conversion program in C language?

Tags: c

The value entered in meters. I want you to be feet and inches.  E.g  1m or 1.80m, but the results always turns out to be 3 feet and 3.37 inches.  I try `cm=m*100` but it does not work. Help please.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float inches = 0.0, feet = 0.0, centimeter = 0.0, meter=0.0, FEET2CM = 30.48,
      INCHTOCM = 2.54;

    printf("Enter your input for meter:");
    scanf("%f", &meter);
    centimeter = meter * 100;
    printf("%.f centimeter is equal to ", centimeter);

    if (centimeter >= FEET2CM) {
        while (1) {
            feet++;
            centimeter = centimeter - FEET2CM;
            if (centimeter < FEET2CM)
                break;
        }
    }

    inches = centimeter/INCHTOCM;

    printf("%.2f feet and %.2f inches\n", feet, inches);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. See [ask] to help complete your question, for example you should provide the result you have obtained with some entered value.

Comment: 1 meter is about 3 feet, 3.37 inches.  So what is wrong with that?

Comment: What are you inputting? I guess perhaps you are typing `1,80` instead of `1.80`. Try outputting `meter` as soon as you have input it, to check this.

Comment: the INCHTOCM and FEET2CM should be either #defines or const.  and the values should be written like so:  const float INCHTOCM = 2.54f;  (note the trailing 'f') other wise a double value is being declared then converted to float

Comment: the returned value from scanf() (and family) should always be checked to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Comment: meter is a float, so the '100' should be '100.0f'

Comment: The code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cleanup of your posted code:

- error checking has been added
- proper definition of fixed conversion values has been applied
- proper definition of magic numbers has been applied

This code complies cleanly, has been tested, and works correctly, given the conversion values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FEET2CM  (30.48f)
#define INCHTOCM (2.54f)

int main()
{
    float inches     = 0.0f;
    float feet       = 0.0f;
    float centimeter = 0.0f;
    float meter      = 0.0f;

    printf("Enter your input for meter:");
    if( 1 != scanf("%f", &meter) ) { // then, scanf failed
        perror( "scanf failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful
    centimeter = meter * 100.0f;
    printf("%.f centimeter is equal to ", centimeter);

    if (centimeter >= FEET2CM) {
        while (1) {
            feet++;
            centimeter = centimeter - FEET2CM;
            if (centimeter < FEET2CM)
                break;
        } // end while
    } // end if

    inches = centimeter/INCHTOCM;

    printf("%.2f feet and %.2f inches\n", feet, inches);
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Answer (score 1):

A good method would be to convert meters to inches. Then calculate the number of whole feet from those inches. Finally, calculate the remainder of inches in excess of the feet. Something like this (not exact code):

```
int feet, totalInches, remainderInches;

totalInches = (int) (meters * 39.3701);
feet = (int) (totalInches / 12);
remainderInches = totalInches - (feet * 12);
```

Comment: You could use mod, the remainder operator: `remainderInches = totalInches % 12;`

Comment: When I use this way, ı can't find fraction of inc.

Comment: Note: Using `(int)` truncates the conversion.  Better to `round()`.  2) Better to use `100/2.54` (exact ratio)  than `39.3701` (approximation).